# Get NSButtons in NSSegmentedControl in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility, appkit, nssegmentedcontrol

I am struggling with accessibility for NSSegmentedControl on OSX. I want to add accessibility labels to individual segments in NSSegmentedControl. When I turn on Voice over I see that the voice over detects these segments as radio buttons. However I would like to change the description for these buttons. For this I am assuming I would need the reference to the individual NSButtons. Is there a way I can get it?

Otherwise is there any easy way to add accessibility labels to individual accessibility labels?

Comment: Google found this in the archives of the Accessibility Mailing List: [NSSegmentedControl](http://www.lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2009/Nov/msg00026.html). It needs a bit of updating.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks :) That worked

Comment: Unfortunately that link is now dead.

Comment: Well, I answered this with a way to do it using NSImage’s accessibilityDescription, but it was deleted as a duplicate answer, so if you have this problem and you think that might help, search for other problems relating to accessibility for NSSegmentedControl.